# What is the meaning of "one of the crews' not-always-legal jobs -- this time a bank heist"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0379786/synopsis)

> one of the crews' not-always-legal jobs -- this time a bank heist.

So can anyone explain this sentence to me.

Comment: It strikes me as: The crew does not always do legal jobs. This time, they are involved in a robbery.

Comment: Is this a complete sentence? Or you cut it short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They hyphen (-) is being used to construct an adjective

> not-always-legal jobs

These are jobs that are *not always legal*. In other words, the crew does jobs and these jobs are *not always legal*. In fact, this time, the job is a bank heist.